# Sonar Unit Tests Coverage Broken

Tags: sonarqube

We upgrade Sonar from ver 3.7.x to 4.1.2 to 4.3.2 and we found that the Unit Tests Coverage is broken.

The Unit Tests Coverage % field is empty while the Unit Tests success is showing 100%.

For testing I setup a Sonar test instance ver 3.7.4 and the reports are working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Months later :-) I got the same - it seems you now need to explicitly setup the coverage (as was always the case with failsafe plugin for integration tests).

The simplest way is to use the jacoco-maven-plugin inside your sonar profile and the then leave the surefire/failsafe plugins as normal (ie. don't override in sonar profile).  Note; if you're using argLine in either plugin for other stuff then specify it as [`<argLine>${argLine} -your -extra -arguments</argLine>`](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html).  Just add the following for coverage in both unit and integration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

**Less Favourable Alternative**

I'd first got unit coverage working in the same somewhat clunky way I'd previously used failsafe (using argLine and a dependency on jacoco), with:

```
<properties>
    <version.jacoco>0.7.2.201409121644</version.jacoco>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/target/report/jacoco-unittest.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/target/report/jacoco-integrationtest.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
</properties>
```

and:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/${version.jacoco}/org.jacoco.agent-${version.jacoco}-runtime.jar=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</argLine>
        <parallel>false</parallel>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jacoco}</version>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <optional>false</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```